# JavaScript Nested for showing wrong results

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I am having trouble with this code and can not figure it out. It appears to add to "data" rather than to "ticket" from "data" like it should. Using code in Google Script

```
function consolidate(){
  var data = [[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,2,1,2,1,2]];
  var ticket = [];
  ticket[0] = data[0];
  for(var x=0;x<data.length;x++){
    for(var i=0;i<ticket.length;i++){
      if(ticket[i][0]==data[x][0]&&ticket[i][1]==data[x][1]&&ticket[i][2]==data[x][2]&&ticket[i][4]==data[x][4]){
        ticket[i][3]=ticket[i][3]+data[x][3];
        ticket[i][5]=ticket[i][5]+data[x][5];
        break;
      } 
    }
    ticket[i]=data[x];
  }
}
```

my result for data is 
    [[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4], [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]] 
but data should not change

Comment: What is the purpose of `ticket[i]=data[x];` if it is outside of the `i` loop?

Comment: Data will change because by doing `ticket[0] = data[0];` you are essentially assigning an object reference.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I was trying to set the first row of data into ticket to start the loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
function consolidate(){
  var data = [[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2],
              [1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2],[1,2,1,2,1,2]];
  var ticket = [];
  ticket[0] = data[0].slice();
  for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < ticket.length; i++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
         if (ticket[i][k] != data[x][k])
             break;
         else if (k != 4)
             continue;
         ticket[i][3] += data[x][3];
         ticket[i][5] += data[x][5];
      } 
    }
    ticket[i] = data[x].slice();
  }  
  console.log(data);
}

consolidate();
```

Comment: So this wasn't what we are trying to accomplish. We are searching through rows of 'data'. When we find like data at "columns" 0,1,2, and 4. Then we will add "columns" 3 and 5 from 'data' onto the same columns of 'ticket'. If the loop can not find like "columns" of 0,1,2 and 4 then a new row will be added to 'ticket' resembling that row from 'data'. So we should end up with fewer rows and some rows  where "columns" 0,1,2 and 4 are the same will have added totals in "columns" 3 and 5

Answer (score 0):

This is where I got and it works. If there is a way to make it better please let me know

```
function consolidate1(){// put data in here <-----()
  var data = [[1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[3,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[3,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]];
  var ticket = [];
  ticket[0]=[];
  ticket[0][0]=data[0][0];
  ticket[0][1]=data[0][1];
  ticket[0][2]=data[0][2];
  ticket[0][3]=data[0][3];
  ticket[0][4]=data[0][4];
  ticket[0][5]=data[0][5];
  for(var x=1;x<data.length;x++){ //get all the unique rows based on columns 0,1,2,4 
  var indicator = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<ticket.length;i++){
      if(ticket[i][0]==data[x][0] && ticket[i][1]==data[x][1] && ticket[i][2]==data[x][2] && ticket[i][4]==data[x][4]){
        ticket[i][3]=ticket[i][3]+data[x][3];
        ticket[i][5]=ticket[i][5]+data[x][5];
        indicator = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(indicator==0){
      ticket[i]=[];
      ticket[i][0]=data[x][0];
      ticket[i][1]=data[x][1];
      ticket[i][2]=data[x][2];
      ticket[i][3]=data[x][3];
      ticket[i][4]=data[x][4];
      ticket[i][5]=data[x][5];
    }
  }
  Logger.log(ticket);
}
```